Building a cpython executable using pyenv suitable for debugging in Eclipse
There are instructions how to build a debug version of python using pyenv. There are two options on pyenv install that seem pertinent. The obvious one is -g, for a debug version. However, there is also -k, which keeps the source tree in $PYENV_BUILD_ROOT after installation. Eclipse is a visual IDE that displays source code. Is it necessary to supply the -k option in order for display of source code lines when debugging cpython?
